# UnityFramework-Swift.h file not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine, cocoapods

I have an error 'Lexical or Preprocessor Issue Group' with building xcode project after have built from Unity.
'UnityFramework/UnityFramework-Swift.h file not found'

[image]

I have Nice Vibration asset and FB SDK in my project. So I tried to follow this instructions in 'Building for iOS' section, but have no result https://nice-vibrations-docs.moremountains.com/platform-specifics.html#building-for-ios

I makes it with .xcworkspace, not .xcodeproj file. I have read it's right way because of FB SDK needs CocoaPods build pipeline and I should use .xcworkspace. And it's happens in XCode 12, if it matters.

What could be wrong? I spent a few hours and so still there, where I have been :(

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue today (although because of the Firebase SDK, not FB).

The problems seems to be with the post-build processor, which modifies the output XCode project. The NiceVibrations implementation currently only copies a single file (`module.modulemap`) to the build directory. Instead, we need the entire `NiceVibrations/Common/Plugins/iOS/Swift` directory to be copied over.

While I can't publish the entire file, I will share my modifications with you for automating this process.

Open the following file:
`NiceVibrations/Common/Scripts/Editor/MMNVBuildPostProcessor.cs`

Locate the `WritePropertiesToFramework` function and replace:

`System.IO.File.Copy(privateModuleFilepath, destination);`

With this:

`DirectoryCopy(Path.GetDirectoryName(privateModuleFilepath), Path.GetDirectoryName(destination), true);`

You can find the source code for the `DirectoryCopy` function from the Microsoft dotnet docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-copy-directories)
**Edit:** You will have to change the second argument of `file.CopyTo` to `true` to allow for subsequent rebuilding atop the same directory to avoid runtime errors

Additionally, I have increased the `callbackOrder` to `60` to ensure that this hook runs last.

I am personally using .xcodeproj instead of workspaces, but it should work fine with workspaces as well. (Firebase uses something called `External dependency manager` which allows you to configure your project generation preference)

After making these changes, trigger a build from unity and "replace" the target folder to update your XCode files!

Comment: Thank you! But I rebuild from unity several times, rebuild in xcode and it's finaly works. I don't know why) And I didn't change anything